# make show/hide work with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code to make the jquery show/hide but somehow it is not working, not even alert is shown in this

```
<div class="col-md-3 clr">
          <label class="clr">License Type</label>
          <div class="clr">
            <select name="licenseType" id="licenseType" multiple>
              <option value="Truck License">Truck License</option>
              <option value="Car License" selected>Car Licence</option>
              <option value="Two Wheeler">Two Wheeler</option>
              <option value="Four Wheeler">Four Wheeler</option>
              <option value="Six Wheeler">Six Wheeler</option>
              <option value="Eight Wheeler">Eight Wheeler</option>
              <option value="Special License" class="special">Special License</option>
              <option value="Machine Operator License" class="machine">Machine Operator License</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 clr specialLicense">
          <label class="clr">Special Machine Operator Licence Number & Type</label>
          <div class="clr">
            <input type="text" name="licenceSpecialMachine" id="licenceSpecialMachine" placeholder="Special Machine Operator Licence Number" class="form-control" />
          </div>
        </div>
```

JS Code

```
 $(".specialLicense").hide();
    $('select[class="special"]').click(function(){
        alert("hi");
        $(".specialLicense").toggle('slow');
    });
```

Comment: is your jQuery within a document ready call?

Comment: Should this ever work? I dont see a `select` with that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @RashminJaviya mentioned, it's important to perform your jQuery after the DOM has loaded. (Alternatively you can [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) your event listener.)

Also, I recommend using [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) to detect any change to the select list, rather than `click()` to detect a click on any option.

It seems that you want a field to show when a particular option is selected, and that you want the field to hide when any other option is selected.

Here, I am using `$('option:selected',this).hasClass('special')` to test the class (`special`) of the selected option (`option:selected`) in the select list (`this`).

```js
$('select#licenseType').change(function () {

    /* the selection has changed */

    if ($('option:selected', this).hasClass('special')) {

        /* the selected option has a class of "special" */
        $(".specialLicense").show('slow');

    } else {

        /* the selected option does NOT have a class of "special" */
        $(".specialLicense").hide('fast');

    }

});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3k6Vc/)

Answer (score 1):

Provided your code is within a document ready call, or at the end of the document, this works:

```
$(".specialLicense").hide();
$('select option.special').click(function () {
    alert("hi");
    $(".specialLicense").toggle('slow');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bRL6X/)**

you wanted `$('select option.special').click(function () {`, not `$('select[class="special"]').click(function(){`.

Answer (score 0):

You're currently selecting the `select` html element, with the class of `special`. For this to work, you need to have an HTML like this

```
<select class="special">
```

But you don't have that type of HTML. So you need this code instead

```
$('select option.special').click(function(){
```

You need to select the option with the `special` class. This would select the event to be triggered if the option with that class is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap code in `document.ready` and use `select option.special` selector to bind click event

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/iamrmin/S2QN9/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".specialLicense").hide();
    $('select option.special').click(function(){
        alert("hi");
        $(".specialLicense").toggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: Does this effect the code because this is also used to make a custom look and feel for the form controls:, The code you all gave me, Thanks for that but it is not working when i try on my local, not an alert is shown

Comment: Here is the code: `$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('input[type=checkbox],input[type=radio]').iCheck({
     checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-blue',
     radioClass: 'iradio_flat-blue'
 });
 
 $('select').select2();
    $('.colorpicker').colorpicker();
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    $('.spinner').spinner();

});`

Comment: @SaberTooth your code is totally different and what is `select2` in `$('select').select2();`? is it method? check console if any errors